# Parse a text file utilizing match in javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing, match

I'm trying to parse a text file and store to an array, but I can't seem to get rid of the unneeded characters.

For example, some of the text will be "fi  nd" or "job;" or "writ,er"

Right now I'm using

```
lettersTemp = InputDataLine.match(/[a-zA-Z]['*]/);
```

to parse the text file, but that obviously isn't working because I'm pulling the entire string and not getting rid of the extra characters. Anyone got some advice or an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Is the result a string that consists of only letters (without space separating words)? If so you can use to the following code to filter the letters;

```
lettersTemp = InputDataLine.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g);
```

And then you can append each line in an array.

If you want to append each word in each line in the array, it seems impossible to realize that.